# SOME/IP - Middleware or IPC

Tags: ipc, middleware

Is **SOME/IP** a *middleware* or an *IPC*? The official SOME/IP page says that it's a middleware, but it acts like an IPC mechanism, similar to CommonApi d-bus. Also, is a Middleware an IPC mechanism?

Answer (score 0):

SOME/IP is just one of the middleware technology available in lower layer. For example, in adaptive autosar, Communication Management uses Proxy/Skeleton structure. And, between them they use IPC. So, SOME/IP can be applied as a lower layer technology here when your subscribed service is in a remote ECU.

You can see in the document how SOME/IP is being used as an implementation of the IPC protocol.
https://www.autosar.org/fileadmin/user_upload/standards/adaptive/20-11/AUTOSAR_EXP_ARAComAPI.pdf